# How to handle large number of if-else statements?

Tags: java

I'm in the middle of creating a game-simulator for a project.  The game consist of two armies fighting each other.  Each army consists of multiple soldiers.  Soldiers are executing instructions (read from text).

Each instruction is a command like move, turn, etc. I have come to the part where I need to create a method that will check what is the next instruction and execute it.  The instructions aren't much similar, meaning they don't have the same methods.

The class running this method stores the game field (2d array) and an array of all soldiers, looping through it and executing the next instruction each soldier has.  So at this point I have a really long list with if-else describing what happens with each instruction. I'm trying to find a better way to write this but can't figure out how. I have knowledge of few design patterns but I cant figure a way to do this with interface or inheritance (not sure if it's even possible).

How do I get around the problem of too many if-else statements and long code?

I know that there might not be enough information here but any advice is appreciated.

Comment: "any advice is appreciated."  1) Apply your shift key once at the start of every sentence and for *every* use of the word 'I'.  2) Ask a question.

Comment: Not sure what the question is... What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Andrew Sorry for not being that careful with grammar . Im asking for techniques to get around the problem I am facing which is too many if-else statements and long code. I believe I have found a way using subclasses (seen at @Chris comment).Im aware that I dont give specific information but describing the problem throughly would take pages . Thanks for your response  anyway.

Comment: Can you edit your title so it is more specific to the question you are asking?  If you ask yourself the question "how would someone with the same question find my question?", that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The instructions aren't much similar, meaning they don't have the same methods [...] How do I get around the problem of too many if-else statements and long code?

In general, if you have "if this type, then do this", then you have a case for polymorphism (a virtual function).  In this case, what each entity has in common is that you're trying to update your game simulation, and each part of your game (each soldier) has a different concept of what it means to update the simulation.

> I have come to the part where I need to create a method that will check what is the next instruction and execute it.

I recommend splitting this into multiple levels of abstraction:

- Representation of the simulation itself
- Getting input from the user (reading the file)
- Translating input into actions in your simulation

The reason you want this sort of independence is that you don't have to re-structure your whole game if you decide to change how you accept simulation input.

**Game simulations**

Every game must set up some sort of initial state, so they know what the world should look like, and how each action should change the world.

After that state it set up, the simulation will iterate through a global loop, commonly called a "game loop", and will keep looping until the simulation is finished (you quit, the game ends, or there is no more input).

**How most games handle their input:**

At the beginning of each game loop, they look for user input since the last time through the loop.  They might look for key presses, mouse input, input on the console, network packets, etc.  They take this input and translate it into actions for their simulation to process.

**How most games handle their simulation:**

Most games make an abstract base class for each game entity, and keep a global collection of all entities.  The entity base class will provide a virtual `Update` method.  This method will take whatever state is necessary to perform the update.

An example, using C# syntax (sorry, I don't know Java)

```
public abstract class GameEntity
{
    public abstract void Update(TimeSpan timeElapsedSinceLastUpdate, World theWorld);
}
```

Each iteration through the game loop, the game will make a sub loop through all the entities, calling `Update` on each of them.  Each game entity will have its own implementation of `Update`.

A specific entity might react to input, or update some internal state.  It might update its position based on its velocity.  It might check for user-induced actions since the last update, to see whether it should change its acceleration/position.  It might check whether enough time has elapsed to transition between game states (e.g. from a `counting-down` state to an `exploding` state).  It might do intersection/collision tests vs other entities in the world.

The point is that time marches forward, and each game entity can have its own independent concept of what it changes vs time.

If your game is turn based (and therefore has no need for a concept of clock-time), or each entity already has a reference to the world, you can remove them from the base `Update` method's signature.  You might also consider adding a `int updateNumber` or `int currentTurn` parameter, if this becomes useful.

**How to handle your simulation:**

You might have soldiers as your only entity type.  Actions will be passed to soldiers independently from the update command.  Then the actions will be performed when update is called.

**How to handle initial state for your simulation:**

You have to figure out how many soldiers you have to start with, and their attributes (type, rank, health, etc).  You might also need information on the world, such as grid size, or possibly terrain data.

**How to handle input:**

- You could feed the actions in when you create the soldiers, keeping track of the action and which turn it should be executed
- You could feed the actions to be executed to each entity before each turn/update

Either way is up to you, but feeding in before each update will let your game be more flexible to change in the future.  In most interactive game, users tend to input moves one turn at a time.

This also won't limit you from creating queues of commands to be executed each turn, since the entity itself doesn't have to process the queue, and so it doesn't have to know such a queue exists.

Comment: I realize the only thing you had a specific question on was "how to handle the if-else", but the title of your question "creating better code quality" seemed to invite the whole-game-architecture interpretation :)

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I have one question. I modified my code so that the instructions will each implement an abstract method. When i call the method the instruction will take an instance of the world and execute the command. I believe that thats better than having a huge method with if-else and lots of casting in my world class . Im just not sure if its ok to pass the world to the instructions what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

You might to want to look at the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

if you think about it, what you are really trying to do, is creating a new language, specialized for your game. It is called a DSL (Domain Specific Language).

This is a really common thing in computer science.

If you think your language will stay really simple, something like that :

```
command1 arg1 ... argn
..
commandN argN1 ... argNn
```

then, you can use the pattern command and find the right command by it name. This is what other response are about.

But this is really BASIC. How do you manage errors ? Too many, not enough arguments ? Eventually conditional expressions or loops? How about sending complex structures or arguments to yours commands ? How about defining a 'macro' or a list of commands ?

If you want more depending of what you really want to do you can go for several routes :

- Using an XML formaat with an XSD
  instead of free text would allow for
  validation time checking of your list
  of orders and their parameter. It
  would also permit use or advenced
  data struscture, macro or simple
  expression. Better, but not so easy
  on the eyes to read.
- Using an existing scripting language
  (like Groovy, Jython, clojure...)
  that can embbed nicely in java, so
  that your commands are in fact source
  code. So they can do everything the
  language permit (so you have loop,
  functions, anything the scripting
  language can do), and you expose the
  API that allow to control your
  soldiers in it.
- You really want something specific. A
  special language, likely more
  advenced than the one in my example,
  but don't want to include a regular
  scripting language. You have a range
  set of tools like XText from Eclipse
  Modeling framework that is designed
  just for that. Helping making a DSL.
  Or you can define a grammar and use
  parsers like ANTR to help you.

This is a very wide topic, if your needs are basic, a big switch case, or the command pattern is enough. If you want something more professional but still effective, I would try one of the other solutions I pointed there and spending time to see what each can really offer, what is possible or not, and how it could serve you... or not.

Comment: So far the instructions were just returning couple of int values .After some thinking I believe that it might be better to move the execution of the instructions to each instruction subclass.But I will look to your solution too. Thanks

Comment: +1.  This gives good information on how to handle consuming the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible :) You'd use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). [Here's an excellent example](http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutor5.htm).

Comment: The way to use polymorphism would be if instructions where getting a reference of the world and then each instruction did its job on that . Im just not sure if it is ok to get them working together or if its better to keep instructions and the world seperate.